# Tkinter how do i summon buttons with different commands assigned to them

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program which displays every admins name like this underneath:

> Their name   More info button which leads the user to their profile.
> but what if I have 20 admins then how would i spawn 20 random buttons with this code?

Code:

```
    i=0 
    adminshower = tk.Toplevel()
    how = len(admins)
    scre = 50 x how
    adminshower.geometry("200"+"x"+scre)
    adminshower.title("Our admins")
    while i != len(admins):
        name = admins[i].get("name")
        adminLabel = Label(adminshower, text=name).grid(row=i, column=0)
code for button here please help:

        i+=1

this button should lead to something like this:

    def moreinfo(name):
        moreinfoshower = tk.Toplevel()
        moreinfoshower.geometry("200x300")
        moreinfoshower.title(adminsname)
        name = "name: "+name
        nameLabel = Label(adminshower, text=name).grid(row=0, column=0) 
        email = accounts[name].get("email")
        email = "email: "+email
        emailLabel = Label(adminshower, text=email).grid(row=1, column=0)  
        user = accounts[name].get("email")
        user = "username: "+user
        usernameLabel = Label(adminshower, text=user).grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Please help and I'm sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: you could loop through a list of all admins name. Though the Q remains unclear, please consider attaching a what you expect vs what you got picture or definition :D

Comment: Maybe you think about another concept. A listbox that stores the values/admin and only a single button that asks which one is selected.

Comment: can i make it spawn buttons beside their name and it redirects it to 1 function which knows what name is chosen and shows the user more info about that selected admin

Comment: you can, yes, but you will need like, you said, 20 buttons defined individually i guess

Comment: so 20 functions?

Comment: actually yes, and it depends upon what way you proceed to

Comment: is there another way of doing it not necessarily with buttons? or is the only way to do it is what Atlas435 stated

Comment: Possiblly yes, but it depends on the data that you want to show

Comment: It will get the information from a nested dictionary which has the admins names as keys so it will display their info like email, name and username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Elaborated on ShayneLord's concept. Thanks to him i have this:

```
    i=0
    k=0
    adminshower = tk.Toplevel()
    how = len(admislist)
    adminbuttons = []
    adminlabels = []
    scre = 25 * how
    scre = str(scre)
    adminshower.geometry("250"+"x"+scre)
    adminshower.title("Our admins")
    while i != len(admislist):
        i+=1
        user = admislist[i].get("username")
        adminlabels.append(Label(adminshower, text=user))  # you don't have to grid after, but you need to if you want to reference the labels again.
        adminlabels[k].grid(row=i, column=0)
        cmd=partial(moreinfo, user)  # It is important you create the command before or use partial() from functools library
        adminbuttons.append(Button(adminshower, text=user, command=cmd))
        adminbuttons[k].grid(row=i, column=15)
        k+=1

        
def moreinfo(user):
    global admislist
    moreinfoshower = tk.Toplevel()
    moreinfoshower.geometry("300x200")
    moreinfoshower.title(user)
    name = accounts[user].get("name")
    email = accounts[user].get("email")
    user = accounts[user].get("username")
    if name == "N/A" and email == "no":
        status = "status: Account not configured"
        pass
    elif name != "N/A" and email == "no" or email !="no" and name == "N/A":
        status = "status: Account is partially configured"
        pass
    else:
        status = "status: Acount is fully configured"
        pass
    nameLabel = Label(moreinfoshower, text=status).grid(row=0, column=0) 
    user = "username: "+user
    usernameLabel = Label(moreinfoshower, text=user).grid(row=1, column=0)
    if name == "N/A":
        name = "Sorry the admin didn't add their name yet, Sorry"
    name = "name: "+name
    nameLabel = Label(moreinfoshower, text=name).grid(row=2, column=0) 
    if email =="no":
        email = "The admin didn't add their email.\n Sorry for the unconvenience"
        pass
    email = "email: "+email
    emailLabel = Label(moreinfoshower, text=email).grid(row=3, column=0)
```